# In an isothermal process there is no change in internal energy, but why in an isobaric one?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, work

- In an isothermal process, the heat Q added (which increases the temperature and internal energy) is exactly cancelled out by the work W done by the gas in the environment (which lowers the temperature and internal energy), so that neither the internal energy nor the temperature of the gas changes.

(Chet Miller (https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/102308/chet-miller), Work done in Isobaric Process, URL (version: 2018-07-05): https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/415224)

But why doesn't this also happen in the isobaric process? Volume work is also done there. But there is a little left over after the volume work (83.15J in my example (picture)), why?

[image]

My question could possibly be a duplicate of my previous one: [Enthalpy, why is work only partially done?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/708515/enthalpy-why-is-work-only-partially-done) i have only made it a little more concrete here (hopefully).

A molecular interpretation would be very helpful, for example i imagined if the gas had only 2 translational degrees of freedom, there would be no change in internal energy in the isobaric process too (166,29J - 166,29J = 0J).

Comment: $\Delta U = nC_v \Delta T$ , $\Delta U=0$ in an isothermal process as $\Delta T=0$ but this isn't true in isobaric process.

Comment: (a) What are you trying to do in the last line of your handwritten piece? I can't make sense of it. (b) have you sketched *p* against *V* graphs for  both the isothermal and isobaric processes?

Comment: @PhilipWood that's the final change in internal energy, I've splittet the processes, first heat was supplied, ∆U rises, but simultaneously work done by the gas removes a little of the internal energy, therefore after the work is done, the change in internal energy is 83,15J instead of 249,44J

Comment: @iwab (a) Thinking in terms of *two* changes in internal energy gives rise to confusion. There is only one such change, and you have calculated it in your second line of mathematics. (b) Because the gas is gaining internal energy AND is also doing work, the HEAT supplied to the gas must be 249, 44 J + 166,29 J (using your figures for $\Delta U$ and $W$). [I don't know what the commas mean, but that's irrelevant.]

Answer (score 2):

> But why doesn't this also happen in the isobaric process? Volume work
> is also done there.

Because unlike the isothermal process where the initial and final temperatures are the same making $\Delta U=0$ for an ideal gas, the final temperature of the isobaric process is greater than the initial temperature resulting in an increase in internal energy.

This can be shown by applying the ideal gas equation to the initial and final states, where

$$\frac{P_{f}V_{f}}{T_{f}}=\frac{P_{i}V_{i}}{T_{i}}$$

For the isobaric process, $P_{f}=P_{i}$. Therefore

$$T_{f}=T_{i}\frac{V_{f}}{V_{i}}$$

Since for the expansion $V_{f}>V_i$ the final temperature if greater than the initial. Finally, since for an ideal gas

$$\Delta U=nC_{v}(T_{f}-T_i)$$

There is an increase in internal energy.

*Bottom line: Not all the heat goes into work because part of it increases the internal energy. The added heat is not "canceled out" by the work done.*

Hope this helps.

Comment: So they heat up (getting faster) and can also do volumework without losing everything from their gained speed again? I think dU/dW have to be constant, nCv(Tf−Ti)/nR(Tf−Ti) = f/2 (f, degree of freedoms). That makes sense, since 166,29J * 3/2 = 249,44J. So i can interpret the degrees of freedom as how much more the internal energy had to increase in order for this volume work to happen. Theoretical thought experiment: What if there were a hypothetical molecule that had only one degree of freedom, then dW done would be greater than dU. Would that make sense?

Comment: @iwab I can't make any sense of what you are saying. Not all the heat goes to work because some of it increases the internal energy. I can't make it any clearer than that. Sorry.

Comment: Isn't that what I also wrote? "So they heat up (getting faster) and can also do volumework without losing everything from their gained speed again?" ≈ "Not all the heat goes to work because some of it increases the internal energy." And f/2 Gives me the ratio between how much internal energy was increased and how much work was accomplished. So how much energy stays in internal energy after work done.

Comment: If it was what you wrote, the way you said it didn't make sense to me. But that's OK, it's probably just me. So let's forget it and move on